# How to specify data type in PyExasol export_to_pandas

Tags: python, exasolution, exasol

How can I pass datatype parameters in export_to_pandas API. and can I change column names to lower cases ?

`from pyexasol import ExaConnection con = ExaConnection(dsn=dns, user=user, password=password) con.execute('OPEN SCHEMA SCHEMATEST1')`

`data = con.export_to_pandas('select * from TABLETEST1')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may specify any parameters used for `pandas.read_csv` and pass it using `callback_params` argument.

For example:

```
callback_params = {
    'names': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
    'header': 0,
    'dtype': {'A': numpy.float64, 'B': numpy.int32, 'C': 'Int64'}
}


data = con.export_to_pandas('select * from TABLETEST1', callback_params=callback_params)
```

Please note that names of columns are actually stored uppercased in Exasol. You may use connection option `lower_ident=True` to lower case for normal `.execute()`, but it is not going to work with `.export_to_pandas`. The only way is to specify column names manually or to modify each name later.